# Passing vector by constant value vs by constant reference

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing

I do understand that in general there is significant difference in passing by value and reference, especially for non trivial types, and that it is mainly whether the object is copied or not, with some caveats when we have an rvalue.

However, I'm wondering whether the compiler actually recognizes that these two things are to some extend identical when the passed argument is constant, and automatically optimizes the pass by value to pass by reference? If not I assume that it is standard to make arguments passed by reference almost always, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general the compiler can't replace a pass-by-value with a pass-by-reference, because in the general case that could introduce an aliasing problem.

The value of the argument could then change underneath the `const`, so to speak:

```
void foo( string const a, string& backarai )
{
    backarai = "Hm! ";
    backarai += a;
}

void bar( string const& a, string& backarai )
{
    backarai = "Hm! ";
    backarai += a;
}

auto main() -> int
{
    string s = "Well well well!";
    foo( s, s );    // Sets s to "Hm! Well well well!"

    string t = "Well well well!";
    bar( t, t );    // Sets t to "Hm! Hm!"
}
```

However, if in a specific case the compiler can *prove* that such aliasing won't be a problem, and that copying a string doesn't have side-effects, and so on, i.e. if it can prove that the observable program behavior in both cases will be the same, then it can optimize this way. That's just the “as if”-rule in action. It permits any optimization where the only observable change is the running time of the code.

Comment: I presume that when all arguments are constant than this would be the case.

Comment: Yes. But it would still have to prove that e.g. copying a string doesn't have side effects. Since `std::string` is provided by the compiler vendor, that is quite possible, but I don't know whether it's done or not.

Comment: Yeah you might be right there. In my case I'm dealing with vectors, but any way it was good to know.